# Distinguish 401 (Unauthorized) / 403 (Forbidden) in Spring Security's AccessDeniedException in Global ExceptionHandler

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have Spring Security implemented in the Spring Boot application which, by default, will correctly throw 401 (Unauthorized) or 403 (Forbidden), such that the following unit tests work:

```
@Test
void notLoggedIn() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/service")) //
            .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized()); // 401 is returned and caught
}

void loggedInWithIncorrectRole() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/service").with(user("someuser").roles("invalidRole"))) //
            .andExpect(status().isForbidden());    // 403 is returned and caught
}
```

Then I added a `@ControllerAdvice` global `ExceptionHandler` to catch all exceptions thrown by the application. Now, all Security exceptions come to the `ExceptionHandler` as `org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied`. Both 401 and 403 become conflated in this exception.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AppExceptionHandler {
    
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleException(Exception e, WebRequest request) {
        log.error(e);
        if ("org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException".equals(e.getClass().getName())) {
            // This will catch BOTH 401 and 403, no distinction
            return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.internalServerError()
                    .body(new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Error occurred));
        }
    }
```

The stack trace is always

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.java:256)
    at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
```

How can I differentiate?

Comment: In your case **UNAUTHORIZED**, `notLoggedIn()` test case is **NOT** handled by the `@ControllerAdvice`

Answer (score 1):

`@ControllerAdvice` cannot handle the `BadCredentialsException`, which is thrown when no user or incorrect credentials are found, as the controller method has not been invoked yet.

In such cases, the `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint` is triggered. If you wish to log all failed attempts, you can create a custom entry point like the one shown below:

```java
public class BasicSecurityEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO: Add your logic here to log the failed attempts
    }

}
```

Ensure to configure it properly:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .httpBasic(c -> c.authenticationEntryPoint(new BasicSecurityEntryPoint()));
    return httpSecurity.build();
}
```